# How to increase FOV in multiplayer?

Tags: pc, call-of-duty-world-at-war

Field of view is extremely low for a PC game, most likely lifted directly from the console versions. I believe that console commands work in multiplayer and aren't considered as cheats (editing game files and memory will almost certainly result in a ban or lock online modes entirely).
There is a ["FOV changer" program](https://github.com/marvinlehmann/CoD-SCZ-FoV-Changer) for the singleplayer and co-op modes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open console by pressing <kbd>~</kbd>/<kbd>§</kbd> and use the command `\cg_fov x` (`x` = your FOV value).
After brief testing, the FOV value hasn't yet reseted back to the default. FOV appears to be capped to "80":

[image: command screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Some people state that changing the FOV may result in a ban, so I wouldn't take the risk. It's considered cheating and some servers block values beyond a certain point anyway.

In multiplayer games the FOV value resets constantly, so you need a key bind to set it back again:

Open the console (<kbd>~</kbd>) and type `bind w +forward;cg_fov <value between 0 and 160>` (or whatever key moves you forward) to make that key both move you forward and change the field of view. The default value is 65 degrees. You can do that with other keys as well.

Comment: The command (for instance `bind w +forward;cg_fov 80`) doesn't work. I can change FOV in MP with `\cg_fov x` and the FOV setting *seems to stick*, even after changing the server and restarting the game.

Comment: It used to work. They might have changed it to get blocked in MP due to many people using it. I haven't played for a long time so I'm not aware of changes regarding this. If your servers accept setting the FOV to 80 it's fine though (although it's strange that it sticks).

Comment: I forgot to mention that your command changes FOV, but only by entering the string manually and doesn't bind it to `W`. FOV is capped at 80 at least in some instances: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLsV5.png

Comment: Also, using dash ("\") was mandatory at least with the `\cg_fov` command.